# How to query the RIPE API for JSON

Tags: ip-address, whois, pywhois

How do you get the RIPE REST API to give you in JSON the same data you'd get from the whois command on the command line?

Eg. Something like the output of

```
whois 1.1.1.1
```

Comment: Why is this being voted to be closed?

Comment: Why? Because you're asking for a service recommendation where whois info is being provided via api (or maybe a library that wraps whois calls for you), and recommendation questions are expressly off-topic. Please review the help center, including [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which calls this out explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do this in Python

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois
from pprint import pprint

ip = "1.1.1.1"
obj = IPWhois(ip)
results = obj.lookup_rdap(depth=1)
pprint(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://whoapi.com/ 
But id imagine there are easier ways and/or cheaper ways
Like setting up a VPS with nodejs backend and using something like so: https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-whois

You would learn more building that (its quick enough to create aswell) than using someone elses API, more customizable for your situation aswell